# How to print all primes which are not greater than the given positive integer N?

Tags: list, prolog

How to print all primes which are not greater than the given positive integer N?

```
a(0). 
a(X) :- b(X). b(X) :- X1 is X - 2, write(X), write(' '), a(X1). 
output:
?- a(20).
20 18 16 14 12 10 8 6 4 2
```

How to be like the example below?

Example:

```
?- a(20). 
   2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19.
```

Comment: have you heard of [this site](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Prolog)?

Comment: @WillNess. Thanks you. This is the first time I know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
divisible(X,Y) :- 0 is X mod Y, !.

divisible(X,Y) :- X > Y+1, divisible(X, Y+1).

isPrime(2) :- true,!.
isPrime(X) :- X < 2,!,false.
isPrime(X) :- not(divisible(X, 2)).

prime(X):- printPrimes(X,0).

printPrimes(X,Y):- X>=Y, isPrime(Y), write(Y), write(' '), Y1 is Y + 1, printPrimes(X,Y1).

printPrimes(X,Y):- X>=Y, \+isPrime(Y), Y1 is Y + 1, printPrimes(X,Y1).
```

Try it like this:

```
?- prime(20).
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19
```

Comment: Great. Thanks bro!

Comment: You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll could define a predicate `is_prime(N)` which succeeds if `N` is prime. And, you have to count up instead of down. :)

```
primes_up_to(N) :-
    N > 1,
    write('2 '),
    primes_up_to(3, N).

primes_up_to(C, N) :-
    C > N.
primes_up_to(C, N) :-
    C =< N,
    write_if_prime(N),
    C1 is C + 2,
    primes_up_to(C1, N).

write_if_prime(N) :-
    (   is_prime(N)
    ->  write(N), write(' ')
    ;   true
    ).
```

I'll leave the definition of `is_prime(N)` as an exercise.

Comment: When i try run in SWI-Prolog is it report: `?- primes_up_to(20).
2 
ERROR: write_if_prime/1: Undefined procedure: is_prime/1
   Exception: (9) is_prime(20) ? No previous search` or
`is_prime(20). ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: is_prime/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)`

Comment: @MargieHayek it's saying `is_prime/1` doesn't exist. As I mentioned in my answer, I am leaving it as an exercise for you to write and define `is_prime/1`.

Comment: Can you give more specific instructions? I tried but no results. Thanks you :)

Comment: @MargieHayek there are a few different ways. You can search this site (`[prolog] is_prime` will find several answers with prime number discussions). You can define `is_prime(2).` (2 is prime), `is_prime(3).`, and you can define `is_prime(N)` for any `N` which is succeeds if `N` is > 3, `N` is odd, and `N` is not divisible by any integer between 3 and the greatest integer less than or equal to sqrt(N).